# Comparar hora Atual Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

Eu tenho uma comparação que verifica se a hora atual é após a hora configurada.

```
LocalTime horaConfig = new LocalTime(6, 00, 00);
LocalTime horaAtual = new LocalTime(20, 00, 00);

horaAtual.isAfter(horaConfig);
```

O meu Problema, é que como a hora atual é 20h a noite, o Joda Time entende que 6h da manhã já é após as 20h. e acaba parando o meu processo. So funcionando se eu colocar um horário ate as 23h.

Existe alguma método para resolver esse problema de comparar com o jodaTime?

Comment: Não é só verificar se uma é menor que a outra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LocalTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) só guarda a informação do horário, não guarda informação do dia, logo, 20h sempre será maior que 6h.

Use [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) ao invés, e indique a data completa, com dia, mês, ano e o horário. Exemplo:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
public class MeuJoda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime dataConfig = DateTime.parse("2014-09-12T06:00:00Z");
        DateTime dataAtual = DateTime.parse("2014-09-11T20:00:00Z");
        System.out.println(dataAtual.isAfter(dataConfig));
    }
}
```

retorna *false*, pois em `dataAtual` eu pus 20h de ontem, e em `dataConfig` eu pus 6h de hoje.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou diretinho para o meu problema.